# VSCode上でNodeJSをデバッグする方法がわかりません。

Tags: javascript, node.js, vscode

環境

リモートOS:CentOS6.10 => npm v6.4.1, nodejs v10.11.0

ローカルOS:Windows10 => 仮想環境: virtualbox, vagrant, エディタ: VSCode

**試してみたこと**

```
[helloworld.js]

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '192.168.33.10');
console.log('Server running at http://192.168.33.10:1337/');
```

このhelloworld.jsを /home/vagrant/nodejsフォルダの中に入れてここに移動し、コマンド 「 node helloworld.js 」と打ちまして

```
[launch.json]

{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Remote",
      "address": "192.168.33.10",
      "port": 1337,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/home/vagrant/nodejs/"
    }
  ]
}
```

そしてこのようにlaunch.jsonを作成しました。

その後、何度かサーバーを実行したりデバッガを実行したりしてみました。

**結果**

```
ランタイム プロセスに接続できません。10000ミリ秒後にタイムアウトします 
-(理由: ターゲットからの応答が正しくないようです。エラー:Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0。 応答: Hello World)。
```

デバッグコンソール上では、

```
Node.js のバージョンを判別できなかったため、インスペクター プロトコルをデバッグしています 
(Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.33.10:1337)
```

↑このようなエラーが出ました。「応答: Hello World」と出ていることからも、なんとなく接続はしているのでは？と思ったのですが、どうもデバッガが実行できないようです。
何か設定にミス等があれば、ご教授頂けると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 今気づいたのは、ローカル上のファイルとリモート上のファイルが同期していないのかな？と思いました。でないとブレークポイントが貼れないのかなと思い至りました…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リモートのnode.jsを以下のようにしてデバックモードで起動して、
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_attaching-to-nodejs

```
node --inspect helloworld.js
```

又は

```
node ----inspect-brk helloworld.js
```

そこに表示されるポート番号（上記のようにプションがなければ9229）を`launch.json`のポート番号に設定するようにすればリモートデバッグが動作するようになると思います。

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Remote",
      "address": "192.168.33.10",
      "port": 9229,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/home/vagrant/nodejs/"
    }
```